# MagicalRecord - how to clear nsfetchedresultscontroller cache and change predicate

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, magicalrecord

The following works one time:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [Cat MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"age" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate groupBy:@"age" delegate:self inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
```

But setting a new predicate and making this call again does not refresh the data. How can I clear the cache and force the fetchedResultsController to fetch new data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the fetchedResultsController's predicate or sortDesctriptors property.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES];
[[fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

or

```
[[fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];
```

..and you have fetch again

```
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    // Handle you error here
}
```

..and refresh your tableView

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```